# Keep Emacs Evil from switching to normal mode when exiting minibuffer

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, minibuffer

I'm an evil Emacs user. However, I really only use the normal mode for fancy Vim style edits when I find them more convenient than regular Emacs commands. (Mostly fancy bulk editing/yanking/deleting). However, I'm also a huge user of the minibuffer (I do a lot of M-x with ido and flx so I can avoid remembering the more esoteric commands). When I do, evil switches to normal mode automatically after I exit. I find that very annoying/confusing. How can I get it to stop? (preferably in an elegant, non-hackish way).

Thanks,
PythonNut

EDIT:

It appears that the switch to normal mode happens in all windows and in all frames.

Comment: Actually, on inspection. It seems that the switch to normal mode happens when I enter the minibuffer, not when I exit it. The interesting thing is, the contents of `minibuffer-setup-hook` don't include any evil hooks. it's contents are `(minibuffer-depth-setup icicle-minibuffer-setup ido-minibuffer-setup auto-indent-minibuffer-hook rfn-eshadow-setup-minibuffer minibuffer-history-isearch-setup minibuffer-history-initialize)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue; maybe knowing your versions could help anyone to identify your issue.  Can you reproduce your issue with "emacs -q" (plus adding evil to load-path)?

Here is an approach to identify the evil (traditional English meaning) piece of code, if any, that is calling to `evil-normal-state`:

```
(defadvice evil-normal-state (before debug-issue activate)
  (setq debug-on-error t)
  (inexisting-function-will-fail))
```

Eval this just after setting a buffer in the evil-state you want it to be, then go to to the minibuffer with M-x.  Is there an stacktrace?

Comment: It does not happen in emacs -Q. I do get an error: `Error in post-command-hook (evil-mode-check-buffers): (void-function ...)`

Comment: Okay, I found the issue by binary search. I wrapped evil in my own global mode, so I could have evil everywhere. How can I get the behaviour of a global mode without it?

Comment: Fixed it myself :). You win the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You may reactivate evil-mode by adding whatever function you use to activate it to `minibuffer-exit-hook`.

Comment: Whatever happens, it happens after the call to minibuffer-exit-hook. `(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 'evil-emacs-state)` doesn't stop the change to normal mode.

Comment: I am not familiar with evil so I cannot comment on `evil-emacs-state`, but what about using this in the hook `(run-with-timer 0.2 nil 'evil-emacs-state)` (with a lambda).  It is sort of a hack: the code will run 0.2 secs after exiting minibuffer.

Comment: That works, but evil still seems confused about state. My modeline is colored by evil state, and it's still in normal-mode even though evil is actually in insert-mode.